# Is there a way to make a custom Page type?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, wp-list-pages

In a theme I'm building, there are two main types of page. One is a product-gallery, one is for general info. I'd like to use `wp_get_pages()` or `wp_list_pages()` twice in the sidebar, one with a list of one type of page, and one with the other.

I don't want to hard-code `include` or `exclude` in either list, as I can't predict which page IDs will be which type of page. So I'd like to do something like:

> wp_list_pages('type=gallery')

and

> wp_list_pages('type=page')

What technique should I be using here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [hierarchical custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types), then pass `post_type` to [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'gallery'
);
wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow to have `post_type` argument to include wp native pages and all hierarchical Custom Post Types, that are added dynamically - meaning that I won't know their names, but know that they are added dynamically. Thanks!

Comment: @dashaluna - you can get all registered post types via [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types),but as far as I know, the `post_type` argument of `wp_list_pages` can only be a single post type, not an array of types. you could use `WP_Query` instead though, which accepts an array of post types.